# Using templates to pass undeclared types

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>
void call(T in){}

struct test{
  using type_t = int;
  void f() {
    type_t a = 1;
    call(a);
  }
};

int main(){
 test t;
 t.f();
 return 0;
}
```

Above compiles normally. My question is how can the compiler deduce `T` to `type_t` correctly? `type_t` is only available inside the scope of `struct test`.

i.e if change `call` to

```
void call(type_t in){}
```

I get the expect error message of `'type_t' was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: _"type_t is only available inside the scope"_ Don't think of it that way - it's not true.  `type_t` is only available *after* it has been defined.  The template deduction is occuring *after* `type_t` has been defined.

Comment: The compiler doesn't deduce `T` to `type_t`, it deduces it to `int`. To better demonstrate your question you can make `type_t` a nested class.

Comment: If the compiler wasn't able to figure out that `type_t` is an alias for `int`, you wouldn't be allowed to define `a` with this type. Since you can declare `a` using that type, the compiler also will be able to figure out that in `call(a)` `a` is an `int`, so the compiler can choose to instanciate `call<int>` at this point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type_t` being declared in `test` is not a problem. For example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void call(T in) {}

struct test {
    using type_t = ...;
    void f() {
        // deduces:                 T = test::type_t
        // implicitly instantiates: void call<test::type_t>(test::type_t)
        call(type_t{});
    }
}
```

Even if `type_t` was private within `test`, this would work just fine, because access-specifiers don't prevent us from instantiating templates.

In your example, it's even less of an issue, because `type_t = int`, and `type_t` isn't a distinct type but an alias. As a result, the compiler deduces `T = int` and instantiates `call<int>(int)`.

Comment: "access modifiers don't prevent us from instantiating templates" > I wanted to check the standard for that, but all I found was [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.spec#general-6) which specifies "explicit instantiation or explicit specialization". Do you know why implicit instantiations behave the same way? Or rather, why it's not mentioned in the draft (or if it is, then where)?

Comment: @Nelfeal access control is only about restricting your ability to name things. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.access#general-6. When you implicitly instantiate a template, you're not naming any class members, it all happens in the background. You have to actually write `test::type_t` for any access control to be checked.

Comment: to clarify, what I don't get and is counter intuitive in this case is, type_t is only a defined type within the scope of struct test. The only way I can picture this working is that the compiler hits call(a); within my struct and then generates a function for it based on the template. Since it's already in the scope of test it knows what type_t is and goes on generating the function behind the scene.

Comment: @Dan yes, that's pretty much how it works. The fact that `type_t` is defined in `test` is only relevant for name lookup. You can call the `call` function with types defined in any scope, and this will simply instantiate `call` with the type from that scope. This works because templates are ultimately doing copy/paste in a sense, so they can use types that aren't visible in the scope of the template, but only in the scope of whatever uses the template.

Answer (score 0):

`type_t`, here, is a public type alias (because structs' default visibility is public). It is accessible from the outside if needed.

And even then, I don't think it would change anything if it weren't public.

You're confusing types that are accessible to the people who use your API, and types that are accessible to the compiler (which is every type).

This distinction was used in C to circumvent the lack of encapsulation: user's couldn't create instances "manually" but were expected to provide one in functions; they could only get an instance through specific functions (think `fopen`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're kind of confusing names with the things they refer to.

For example, in this code:

```cpp
struct test{
  using type_t = int;
  void f() {
    type_t a = 1;
    call(a);
  }
};
```

`type_t` is a name. It has a scope almost like any other name, and outside that scope the compiler won't use it (not because it couldn't, but because the whole point of scopes is the limit the visibility of names so it won't).

Trying to use that name outside that scope, like: `void call(type_t in){}` is bound to fail simply because the compiler can't find that name. We can make it work by 1) rearranging the code so `type_t` has been declared by the time we try to use it in `call`, and 2) adding a scope resolution operator so the compiler can/will find it:

```cpp
struct test{
  using type_t = int;
  void f();
};

void call(test::type_t in) 

void test::f() {
  type_t a = 1;
  call(a);
}
```

So, to have access to the names, we just have to arrange the code so each name has been declared before we try to use it. In this case, there's enough interaction between `call` and `test` that we need to arrange everything in a specific order for it to work (a decent sign that in real life, this may not be a great design).

That's not how the original code worked though. It didn't share the *name* `type_t` from `test` to `call`. It just declared `type_t` as an alias for `int`, and then passed a parameter of that type to `call`, which resulted in `call<int>` being instantiated and used. That doesn't depend on the name `type_t` being *visible* to the template at all though. For this, the compiler only really cares about the underlying type being referred to, not the name.

For that matter, the type we use to instantiate a template doesn't even need to have a name at all. For example:

```cpp
template <class T>
void func(T t) { t(); }

struct foo {
    foo() {
        auto unknown_t = [] { std::cout << "lambda!\n"; };

        func(unknown_t);
    }
};
```

A lambda expression basically creates a class that doesn't even have an actual name-but we can still use its type to instantiate a template just fine.

#### Summary

So, if we use a name, that name has to be visible where we use it (has been seen by the compiler, and is in scope). But the name of a type doesn't have to be visible for that type to be used to instantiate a template. In fact, the type doesn't need to have a name at all.

Comment: anyways, I know the difference between types, variables, scope etc. 
What I don't get and is counter intuitive in this case is, `type_t` is only a defined type within the scope of `struct test`. The only way I can picture this working is that the compiler hits `call(a);` within my struct and then generates a function for it based on the template. Since it's already in the scope of `test` it knows what `type_t` is and goes on generating the function behind the scene.

Comment: @Dan: That's sounds about right, but this does get into an area of C++ that really is complex. When you use a symbol to instantiate a template, that symbol is looked up *both* in the context of the instantiation, *and* the context where the template is defined. And then there's Koenig lookup, where the name of the function you invoke is looked up in the namespace of the parameter(s) you pass, so if you have `Foo::bar x; f(x);`, the `f` could mean `f` in the local scope, or `Foo::f` (and even though it turns out to be useful, just about everybody agrees this is ugly).